# Facebook iOS SDK is not working on device (requires valid redirect URI) but in simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, sdk, ios-simulator

I know there are already a few topics like this, but I red them all and I haven't found the solution yet.

I implemented the Facebook iOS SDK as in the [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) described, every single step, but on my iPad it is opening Safari with Facebook and it is prompting me to login.

So far so good, but then I see the blue bar on the top with Cancel, appname and Login, nothing else. Either when Im pressing Cancel or Login I get the following error:

> An error has occurred in your app... (translated from german)
>   API Error Code: 100
>   API Error Description: Invalid parameter
>   Error Message: Requires valid redirect URI.

I have no idea, what to do. I double checked App-ID, info.plist, switched on and off Enhanced Auth Dialog in FB settings.

In the simulator I can see the result as in the tutorial described, without any error.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

PS: There are some warning about unimplemented methods in xcode. fbSessionInvalidated and fbDidNotLogin are missing, where do I get them from?

---

Difference between device and simulator. The dialogs on the device are in german, in the simulator in english. Don't know if that might be importend.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, after spending a day of troubleshooting...

The safari setting "private surfing" (Privates Surfen) was switched on and disturbed the communication between app and facebook sdk.

I switched it off and everything runs like charm and like in the simulator (where this setting isn't existing).

Hope this helps somebody else.